# document management system

Tags: report

I am writing technical documents with math/diagrams/plots/code etc. I want to compile them into a single document and also must be able to run each of them independently.
These technical documents belonging to each topic are in their floders. 
Can someone guide me how to manage it better and also make it portable? Like I work on the same documents on Mac OSX/MS Windows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand the question correct, then a solution could be using the package `subfiles`.

Say that `main.tex` is your main file, and `file1.tex`, `file2.tex`, and `file3.tex` are the ones you want to include. Then your main document would look something like:

**main.txt**:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
<your preamble>
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\subfile{file1}

\subfile{file2}

\subfile{file3}

\end{document}
```

where you are allowed to put text everywhere you like, just as if you where using `\include` or `\input` instead of `\subfile`. The contents of `file1.tex` would then look something like

**file1.tex**

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}

<your document goes here>

\end{document}
```

The same structure should apply to the files `file2.tex` and `file3.tex`.

Now when you compile `main.tex` then the contents of the files, that is, what I indicated by <*your document goes here*> will be included in your document, and if you compile, say `file1.tex`, then the contents of `file2.tex` will be compiled as if it had the documentclass specifications and preamble of `main.tex`.

So now all the files in the project can be compiled seperately, but to compile one the subfiles you will need to have `main.tex` in the same directory.

**documentation and installation of the package**

I am not sure whether `subfiles` comes as a standart package. It did not for me, so depending on how experienced you are with installing packages I wanted to say that the pacakges can be found at

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfiles/

where there also is a documentation of the package, namely the pdf document `subfiles.pdf`. If you don't know how to handle `.ins` and `.dtx` files then there is a small guide at

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Installing_Extra_Packages

and if you want you can put the files `subfiles.cls` and `subfiles.sty` which are generated while building the package in the same directory as `main.tex`, so that you are not depending on the fact that the next system on which the files need to be compiled has the package `subfiels` installed.

**EDIT**

To answer

> I have three levels of directory, 1 - toplevel which has rootfile.tex, 2- chapter level which has the main file of each chapter, 3- section level which has the actual contents of that chapter. I am instantiating 3 in 2 using \include{./Sections/part1}. How can manage such a system using subfiles? – avlsi

Suppose that you have the files

```
./rootfile.tex
./chapter/chap1.tex
./chapter/chap1/section1.1.tex
./chapter/chap1/section1.2.tex
./chapter/chap2.tex
./chapter/chap2/section2.1.tex
./chapter/chap2/section2.2.tex
./chapter/chap3.tex
./chapter/chap3/section3.1.tex
./chapter/chap3/section3.2.tex
```

and you want to include the files `sectionX.1.tex` and `sectionX.2.tex` in the file `chapX.tex` for X=1,2 and still be able to compile both your section files, your chapterfiles and your root file. This can be done by letting your files look something like:

**rootfile.tex:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
<your preamble>
\usepackage{subfiles}

\def\dirlevel{../}

\begin{document}
\def\dirlevel{}

\subfile{./chapter/chap1}
\subfile{./chapter/chap2}
\subfile{./chapter/chap3}

\end{document}
```

**chapX.tex:**

```
\documentclass[./../rootfile.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}

\subfile{./\dirlevel chap/chapX/sectionX.1}
\subfile{./\dirlevel chap/chapX/sectionX.2}

\end{document}
```

**sectionX.Y.tex:**

```
\documentclass[./../../rootfile.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}

<your section goes here>

\end{document}
```

The trick is that `\def\dirlevel{}` is only read if you compile `rootfile.tex`, whilst `\def\dirlevel{../}` is read no matter which of the files you compile, so no matter which file you compile LaTeX will still be able to find your files.

Comment: I have three levels of directory, 1 - toplevel which has rootfile.tex, 2- chapter level which has the main file of each chapter, 3- section level which has the actual contents of that chapter. I am instantiating 3 in 2 using \include{./Sections/part1}. How can manage such a system using subfiles?

Comment: that really worked like a charm. But I have issue with the image file paths. All my images are in ./chap1/images and they are included in ./chap1/sections/part1.tex. When i run ./chap1/chap1.tex, I get correct output. But when i run ./rootfile.tex it is not able to find the image file. The following is the way I am including the images in the sections. \includegraphics[width=\ScaleIfNeeded]{./Images/basic.ps}

Comment: @avlsi Do you actually need to compile your section files individually? If not then I belive that you can just replace the path ``./images/basic.ps`` with ``./\dirleve chap1/images/basic.ps``, but I don't believe that you will be able to compile your section files correctly then.

Comment: my documents are not really a thesis. But individual independent documents. So I was thinking a best way to consolidate them with proper table of contents etc. Is there a way to give a master path to these image paths, so that they donot get disturbed when compiling? Like $IMAGEFILE_ROOT/chap1/images/basic.ps

Comment: @avlsi: I don't understand what your setup is, which files you have, which ones you want to be able to compile and what you mean by disturbing your files.

Comment: I will explain the directory structure, 1-./rootfile.tex 2-./chapters/chap1/master.tex & ./chapters/chap1/images 3-./chapters/chap1/sections/seca.tex & ./chapters/chap1/sections/secb.tex. And the images are included inside seca.tex/secb.tex and sometimes in master.tex. I have written these documents long back and now I want them to be compiled into a single report so that I can use the .pdf effectively for personal use.

Comment: @avlsi: You don't really tell me much. I still don't know what was wrong with the solotion of changing ``./images/basic.ps`` with ``./\dirleve chap1/images/basic.ps`` in the ``\includegraphics`` command? And which files do you need to compile?

Comment: thanks for the input, I managed to get the thing working with what you have previously mentioned.

Comment: Since you have some response below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Comment: i am again back to square w.r.t image management. dir hierarchy 1. root 2. root/chapters/chap1/chap1_root.tex 3. root/chapters/chap1/sections/seca.tex. I have defined \def\dirlevel{../../} in root.tex. and image is instantiated in seca.tex as \includegraphics[width=\ScaleIfNeeded]{\dirlevel chapters/chap1/images/abc/basic_idea}. LaTeX Error: File `chapters/chap1/images/abc/basic_idea' not found. How to update this image path in seca.tex ?